# setonItemLongClickListener is not setting attribute to the right position in custom listview

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemlongclicklistener

Say I have 5 items in my list. If I long press an item, a toast message appears giving the position I pressed which is correct, but I have an `ImageView` that I want to make visible once I long press an item at that position. The problem is that the `ImageView` is always appearing at the bottom of the list and not the position I selected. Here's my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<small>" + GalleryActivity.item + "</small>"));

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });




    listOfImages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOfImages);
    customAdaptor = new CustomAdaptor();
    listOfImages.setAdapter(customAdaptor);
    listOfImages.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, "You pressed at position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            delete.setClickable(true);
            delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            return true;
        }
    });

}
class CustomAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);

        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.customImage);
        delete = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        test = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.test);

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        loadImageFromUrl(images.get(position));




        return view;
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to inflate the `convertView` in `getView(...)`. You are inflating always the last view so your result is at the end.

Comment: You should look into the [ViewHolder pattern](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object `delete` does not contain the current position image because you do not tell him to do so. `delete` contains the last things you affect to him -> the last image of the list.

You need inside your listener to get the right image, then to make it visible

```
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, "You pressed at position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        delete = view.findViewById(R.id.delete); //select the right image

        delete.setClickable(true);
        delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm.